# If $f$ is analytic defined on $D:=\{z:|z|<1\}$ and $|f(z)|\le 1$, can $f$ be extended continuously to $\overline D$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analyticity

If $f$ is analytic defined on $D:=\{z:|z|<1\}$ and $|f(z)|\le 1$, can $f$ always be extended continuously to $\overline D$? In other words, can all analytic functions $f:D\to\overline D$ be extended to continuous functions $\tilde f:\overline D\to\overline D$ (such that $\tilde f|_D=f$)?

Ideally, for $|z_0|=1$, we could simply define $f(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)$. It seems like a reasonable assumption that this extended version of $f$ exists and is continuous, but it's not obvious to me that these limits must exist. This feels like it should be a standard result in complex analysis, but I haven't been able to find a good reference.

(Unfortunately, the hope that $f$ can be extended to an *analytic* function is dashed by the example of $\sqrt{z-1}$.)

Comment: It is a theorem of Fatou that bounded holomorphic functions in the unit disc have radial (and more generally non tangential limits) ae on the unit circle and for any closed subset of measure zero on the circle it is standard to construct such which have no radial limits there: however one can easily construct bounded holomorphic functions that do not have general limits anywhere on the circle (Blaschke products with zeroes that accumulate at any point of the unit circle) so the non tangential part is essential

Comment: @Conrad How does one construct a function which has no radial limits at _one_ point?

Comment: The construction is not that simple (and applies for any closed, or more generally $F_{\sigma}$ set of measure zero) and can be found for example as theorem 2.7 in Collingwood and Lohwater Theory of Cluster Sets; one looks at $\frac{z+\alpha_k}{\alpha_k-z}$ where $\alpha_k \to 1$ very fast on the unit circle and construct $f$ a linear combination of such with positive coefficients, that converges normally in the open unit disc, st on two subsequences, $f(r_k) \to \infty, r_k \to 1$ and  $f(\rho_k)$ bounded for $\rho_k \to 1$; since by construction $\Re f>0$ in the unit disc, $e^{-f}$ works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $f(z) = e^{(z+1)/(z-1)}$. The map $z\mapsto \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ takes the unit circle to the imaginary axis and the interior of the unit circle to the left half-plane; therefore $f(z)$ is indeed a map from $D$ to itself. However, $f(x)$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $1$ from below, but $|f(e^{i\theta})|=1$ and thus $f(z)$ cannot tend to $0$ as $\theta\to0$.

Comment: Follow-up question: are the _radial limits_ $\lim_{t\to 1^-}f(tz_0)$ always defined for $t$ real and $z_0$ on the circle?

Comment: I don't understand why $f(e^{i\theta})$ tends to $1$ as $\theta\to0$.

Comment: Indeed, as $\theta\to0$, it seems like $f(e^{i\theta})$ has argument $-\cot(\theta/2)$, which has no limit at all (it spins all around the unit circle infinitely fast).

Comment: If $\theta \uparrow 0$ then there is no limit, I am not sure why the answer asserts that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake—luckily the proof survived the fix. The radial limits do exist for all $z_0\in S^1\setminus\{1\}$—indeed $f(z)$ is a holomorphic and thus continuous function on all of $\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: Nice. Maybe an easier finish for some: suppose $f$ continuous on $\overline D$... $f$ is non-zero and analytic in $D$ so by minimum (maximum) modulus theorem it takes minimum (maximum) modulus on $S^1$ and for $z\in S^1-\{1\}$ this modulus is 1, which implies $f$ is constant.

Comment: @user8675309 Ah, so our only save is for $|f|$ to have a limit point of $0$ at $z=1$ (which it does; the set of limit points of $f$ near $1$ is $[0,1]$). This forces $f$ not to have a (necessarily unique) limit there.

Comment: Here's a plot of that function.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mdeuiyxmnh
The x-axis is the real part of the input; the slider is the imaginary part. Blue and purple are the real and imaginary parts of the output.